# I can't print my array by individual line, only one long string

Tags: java, arrays

When I run this code I only get a long list of names like this :

```
Jones, Jon BS, Wells, Lisa HS, Ryes, Ric DR
```

but what I want is it to print each one individually

```
Jones, Jon BS
Wells, Lisa HS
Ryes, Ric DR
```

I'm using two classes for this program my main being

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Arrays;

public class someName
{
public static void main (String[] args)
    {
....//set all my variables and prompted user for number of Inputs
        {
        fName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter "+i+" First Name: ");
        lName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter "+i+" Last Name: ");
        level = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter "+i+" Highest Level of Degree: "); 
        someClass t = new someClass(fName,lName,level);
        listOfName[i] = t;
        }
    for(int i = 0; i<numPerson; i++)
        {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listOfName));
        }
    }       
}
```

when I change the

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listOfName));
```

to

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listOfName[i]));
```

i get an Error stating

```
java:29: error: no suitable method found for toString(someClass)
```

any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i<numTutor; i++)
        {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listOfTutor));
        }
```

to this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i<numTutor; i++)
    {
        System.out.println(listOfTutor[i]);
    }
```

In other words, instead of printing all of `listOfTutor` `numTutor` times, print out each element once.

Or, better yet, use an enhanced for-loop:

```
    for(final Tutor tutor : listOfTutor)
    {
        System.out.println(tutor);
    }
```

(which does the same thing, but without the need for `i` and `numTutor`).

Comment: Darn, I feel like an idiot Thanks. For some reason I thought that would just print out the Array Location (ie `Tutor@89329nfn` or what not. Thanks again will accept as soon as I am able

Comment: this is something I wanted to add also `Arrays.sort(listOfTutors)` right before the print statement you helped me with earlier. However its giving me an Exception that I am unfamiliar with.

Comment: @BradJones: Firstly -- a general recommendation: when asking a question, don't say "it's giving me an exception", say "it's giving me this exception: ..." (where "..." is the actual exception). Secondly -- a general request: when asking a separate question, ask it as a new question, rather than as a comment to an answer on your original question. Thirdly -- I'm guessing that your problem is that `Tutor` doesn't implement `Comparable`, so `Arrays.sort` has no way of telling when one tutor is "less" than another. Check out the Javadoc for `java.lang.Comparable`.

Comment: Thanks again! Sorry for the informality.

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way ...

```
for(int i=0; i<listOfTutor.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(listOfTutor[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 for(int i = 0; i<numTutor; i++)
        {
        System.out.println(listOfTutor[i]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried instead?

```
System.out.println(listOfTutor[i]);
```

or

```
System.out.println(listOfTutor[i].toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use following code

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList; 
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Stipend
{
public static void main (String[] args)
    {
    String fName = "";
    String lName = "";
    String level= "";
    String ans;
    String numStud;
    ans = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter the number of Tutor's: ");
    int numTutor = Integer.parseInt(ans);
    Tutor [] listOfTutor = new Tutor [numTutor];
    for (int i = 0; i<numTutor; i++)
        {
        fName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Tutor "+i+" First Name: ");
        lName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Tutor "+i+" Last Name: ");
        level = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Tutor "+i+" Highest Level of Degree: "); 
        Tutor t = new Tutor(fName,lName,level);
        listOfTutor[i] = t;
        }
    for(int i = 0; i<numTutor; i++)
        {
            System.out.println(listOfTutor[i].toString());
        }
    }       
}


import java.util.Arrays;

public class Tutor
{
String firstName;
String lastName;
String degreeLevel;
String numStudents;
String FormalName;
public Tutor(String firstName, String lastName, String degreeLevel)
    {
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
    this.degreeLevel = degreeLevel;
    this.numStudents = numStudents;
    this.FormalName = lastName +", "+ firstName +" "+ degreeLevel;
    }   
public String toString()
    {
    return(FormalName);
    }   
}
```

I Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Think this should work fine. :)
Hope it helps.

```
for(int i=0; i<listOfTutor.length; i++){ 
   System.out.println(listOfTutor[i].FormalName);
}
```